# Does villager keep his trades after zombification

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a mending villager in my ssp but he sells it for 30 emeralds. I traded 2 times with him . Can I turn him into a zombie villager and then cure him to get a discount. Are there any risks in doing it? There is another page about this but it's in java edition.

**Minecraft-bedrock-edition**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, trades do stay. As you can see there is a massive discount. The only risk is the villager being killed to sunlight.
[image: img]

Answer (score 1):

A villager's trades, jobs, and job experience stay. You will receive massive discounts from the villager after you cure it. Other villagers will give smaller and temporary discounts. Just make sure you don't kill the zombified villager.